# Maven with Spring boot builds but won't run

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have tried everything but can't get Maven to spring-boot:run
I have tried removing the parent and countless google searches
I have also tried apache-spark as a dependency, none of which solved it
I tried using the instructions from spring.io and still had the same problem
I am running "Apache Maven 3.5.0" and got an error that only Apache Maven 4 is supported

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FirstBaptistHazelwood</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my iml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="Spring" name="Spring">
      <configuration />
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="RUNTIME" name="Maven: org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.5.Final" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.5.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:2.1.5.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ognl:ognl:3.0.8" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.javassist:javassist:3.21.0-GA" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.unbescape:unbescape:1.1.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:1.4.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.10" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.3.RELEASE" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

mvn spring-boot:run -e

```
[master@HPArch FirstBaptistHazelwoodBeta]$ mvn spring-boot:run -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/master/Documents/projects/websites/FirstBaptistHazelwoodBeta/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ FirstBaptistHazelwood-Beta ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
19:13:29.204 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
19:13:29.208 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
19:13:29.208 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/home/master/Documents/projects/websites/FirstBaptistHazelwoodBeta/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-05-14 19:13:30.027  INFO 7862 --- [  restartedMain] Application                              : Starting Application with PID 7862 (/home/master/Documents/projects/websites/FirstBaptistHazelwoodBeta/target/classes started by master in /home/master/Documents/projects/websites/FirstBaptistHazelwoodBeta)
2017-05-14 19:13:30.031  INFO 7862 --- [  restartedMain] Application                              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-14 19:13:30.577  INFO 7862 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@460bbf72: startup date [Sun May 14 19:13:30 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-14 19:13:30.626  WARN 7862 --- [  restartedMain] ionWarningsApplicationContextInitializer : 

** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.


2017-05-14 19:13:37.659  WARN 7862 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'greetingController' for bean class [GreetingController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [Controller.GreetingController]
2017-05-14 19:13:37.667 ERROR 7862 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@460bbf72: startup date [Sun May 14 19:13:30 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at Application.main(Application.java:13) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]

2017-05-14 19:13:37.677 ERROR 7862 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'greetingController' for bean class [GreetingController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [Controller.GreetingController]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at Application.main(Application.java:13) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'greetingController' for bean class [GreetingController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [Controller.GreetingController]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:345) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:283) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:135) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:287) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.675 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-14T19:13:37-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/202M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my mvn spring-boot:run --debug
https://pastebin.com/raw/cJvefcXC

Comment: please add exception and stacktrace what you get when you try to run.

Comment: @pvpkiran I added it and debug to my original post just now

Comment: try `mvn clean` then `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: @jmw5598 that doesn't solve it. I get the same generic errors that I can't solve

Comment: do you have a configuration class? if so can you add it.  Its trying to initialize the GreetingController but it has already been initialized

Comment: 1. what is your directory structure. It looks like you have your main SpringBootApplication class under `src/main/java` . Move it under some package `src/main/java/blah/blah/blah` and make sure all your other classes are one level lower than this(for spring boot component scan to work out of the box) 2. Remove your iml from the question, it is of no use. 3. Check cour controller class annotation. You see there is a `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException`

Comment: @pvpkiran That worked. Thank you. I always thouhgt placing it under a package was optional

Comment: No worries. To upvote if its helpful. For more information https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looks at this in the future, pvpkiran informed me of my errors in the comments.

1) Application has to be in a package (src/main/java/x/x/x) in order to work. It is not optional.

2) Delete the *.iml file. Apparently it is not necessary, but in my case it remade itself

3) ConflictingBeanDefinitionException is something in a controller class, so take a break and reexamine it after a while

Thanks again @pvpkiran

Answer (score 0):

Please try `mvnw clean install` and then run the application again.